# Using just Angular.js templates, without the whole framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, client-side-templating

Is it possible to compile Angular.js templates (`ng-show`, `ng-if`, etc) into standalone functions which accept an object and return HTML? Like other templating languages like Handlebars, Underscore.js Templates?

I would like to use the same template in other apps which don't use Angular.js

Answer (score 2):

Those templates are called Directives. Directives are a core part of Angularjs and can only be used in the context of Angularjs.